# SparkJava compiled to native-image does not work

Tags: java, spark-java, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to compile a simple java application based on [spark-java](http://sparkjava.com/) to a native image. The application exposes a single `GET /healthcheck` endpoint which always returns text/plain: `OK`.

There are only two dependencies in the project:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.1'
  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'
}
```

I have created native-image configuration by running fatjar via GraalVM:

```
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=native-image/ -jar javaspark-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar
```

What is important I'm making a REST call to the endpoint to make sure agent can inspect necessary branches in the code. The resulting *.json files are then put into `META-INF/native-image` and therefore are picked automatically by `native-image`.

Then I'm using multistage docker build to compile the fatjar and compile the jar into the native image:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc zlib1g-dev wget

RUN wget https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-19.3.0.2/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-19.3.0.2.tar.gz
RUN tar -vzxf graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-19.3.0.2.tar.gz
ENV PATH /graalvm-ce-java11-19.3.0.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUN gu install native-image

WORKDIR /graalvm-demo
COPY . /graalvm-demo

RUN ./gradlew clean fatJar
RUN native-image --verbose --enable-http -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime --no-fallback -jar /graalvm-demo/build/libs/javaspark-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-alpine-jdk-11.0.3_7-slim
WORKDIR /graalvm-demo
COPY --from=0 /graalvm-demo/javaspark-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar .
RUN apk --update --no-cache add \
  curl \
  tar \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ./javaspark-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar
```

When the docker build is triggered via:

```
docker build . -t app
```

it all looks fine - the image is created and upon start the console does not report any issues:

```
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 11.0.5
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@6260ba9e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @4ms
```

However, when I try to access the endpoint, it does not work:

```
[qtp1802776325-8] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[qtp1802776325-10] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput
```

Does anybody has any idea what am I doing wrong?

The commit within the repository that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/xmcax/javaspark-native/tree/f5636ed39c63e35861840998a21a0b79bf4ff996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out since GraalVM 19.0.x (https://www.graalvm.org/docs/release-notes/19_0/#1900):

> There was a change in how classes are initialized in a native-image. Now, we initialize application classes at run time by default.

That explains why all the tutorials I have seen so far did not mention the issue described in my questions - they were all using the early version of GraalVM where static classes were initialized at build time by default. Applying the same approach fixes the issue. With:

```
RUN native-image \
    -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime \
    -H:+TraceClassInitialization \
    --verbose \
    --enable-http \
    --static \
    --no-fallback \
    --initialize-at-build-time=org.eclipse.jetty,org.slf4j,javax.servlet,org.sparkjava \
    -jar /sparkjava/build/libs/javaspark-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar
```

everything works as expected. With alpine base image the resulting docker image is 26M:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG    IMAGE ID      CREATED              SIZE
ni7          latest dcb94dbfb6ad  About a minute ago   26MB
```

The full solution can be seen here: https://github.com/xmcax/javaspark-native/tree/b9235b1f777de661c0087fbfef4ccaf39303ad3e